# "'origin' must be supplied" error when trying to extend ggplot using a date field

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am playing around with writing an extension to ggplot to add geoms and stats analogous to those available in quantmod.  The first step to this is actually learning how to extend ggplot and I am falling over at this first hurdle because of an error I can't quite understand.  The following code causes the following error "Error during wrapup: 'origin' must be supplied".  I have tried working around it by wrapping the dates with as.Date( , origin = ) but that hasn't helped.  I think I am probably missing something obvious, but I don't know what it is.

```
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

getSymbols("AAPL")

statQSMA <-
  ggproto("statQSMA", Stat,
          compute_group = function(data, scales) {
            data.frame(x = data$date, y = SMA(data$close, n = 20))
          },
          required_aes = c("date", "close")
)

stat_q_sma <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  RetVal <- ggplot2::layer(
    stat = statQSMA, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
  RetVal
}

g <-
  ggplot(AAPL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = index(AAPL), y = AAPL.Adjusted)) +
  stat_q_sma(aes(date = index(AAPL), close = AAPL.Adjusted))
print(g)
```

If "index(AAPL)" is changed to "1:nrow(AAPL)" the above code works fine.  Also geom_line works fine with the x axis being dates, just not stat_q_sma.

```
> head(AAPL)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      11.01952
2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.26411
2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.18389
2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.23912
2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      12.17276
2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.75529
```

Comment: Please include (a subset) of your data with `dput`

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I've added the head of the data to the original question.

Comment: `index` is just returning the row numbers not the rownames. Use `rownames` (or better still move this information into the data.frame and make it a date outside of the ggplot. `ymd` from `lubridate` is the easiest to use.

Comment: index returns a vector of dates when used with an xts object, rownames returns NULL.

If I can move forward and turn this into a package, I would imagine it would mostly get used with xts objects (quantmod's getSymbols returns an xts) rather than data.frames.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that the Date has to be converted to an integer for the x axis.

data.frame(x = as.integer(data$date), ... seems to do the trick.

Comment: It is better to keep it as a date and use the `scale_x_date`. The position scale for time data is explained in [scale_date](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html).